# Parsing JSON in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to access a buried value in Azure Logic APPS Json body. I have the json body from a HTTP response, i want to access the buried value, i'm not sure how i can access it.

In general we'll access the buried value in python with the below code:

```
body.data.alertContext.condition.allOf.dimentions[0].value
```

Demo JSON

```
”Headers”:{},
“body”{
  "schemaId": "azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema",
  "data": {
    "essentials": {
      "alertId": "/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/b9569717-bc32-442f-add5-83a997729330",
      "alertRule": "WCUS-R2-Gen2",
      "severity": "Sev3",
      "signalType": "Metric",
      "monitorCondition": "Resolved",
      "monitoringService": "Platform",
      "alertTargetIDs": [
        "/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourcegroups/pipelinealertrg/providers/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/wcus-r2-gen2"
      ],
      "configurationItems": [
        "wcus-r2-gen2"
      ],
      "originAlertId": "3f2d4487-b0fc-4125-8bd5-7ad17384221e_PipeLineAlertRG_microsoft.insights_metricAlerts_WCUS-R2-Gen2_-117781227",
      "firedDateTime": "2019-03-22T13:58:24.3713213Z",
      "resolvedDateTime": "2019-03-22T14:03:16.2246313Z",
      "description": "",
      "essentialsVersion": "1.0",
      "alertContextVersion": "1.0"
    },
    "alertContext": {
      "properties": null,
      "conditionType": "SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
      "condition": {
        "windowSize": "PT5M",
        "allOf": [
          {
            "metricName": "Percentage CPU",
            "metricNamespace": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "operator": "GreaterThan",
            "threshold": "25",
            "timeAggregation": "Average",
            "dimensions": [
              {
                "name": "ResourceId",
                "value": "3efad9dc-3d50-4eac-9c87-8b3fd6f97e4e"
              }
            ],
            "metricValue": 7.727
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "customProperties": {
      "Key1": "Value1",
      "Key2": "Value2"
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot share the json response due to professional reasons. How can i write a expression to access this string value and set it to a variable in azure logic apps

Comment: You can make use of Parse_JSON action in your workflow to parse the Http response body and then you can assign the value to any avariable

Comment: Can you share a demo json response to help you better

Comment: Sure, i've added the demo json, it's basically the common alert schema.

Comment: Have you tried using Parse Json action?

Comment: Yeah it kinda was throwing an error, not sure how to write the code to access the value inside dimentions.

Comment: Can you share the error message and also your flow diagram?

Comment: Okay, so I used the Parse Json action, then after that i'm trying to send an alert to Slack, I want to send the body.data.alertContext.condition.allOf.dimentions[0].value as a text to it, but i'm not sure how to access this value. The error is it failed, the http webhook to slack failed stating no body, it was unable to parse and select the value, since it's inside an array it's not directly accessible.

If there is any method to access it like with for each, do let me know

Answer (score 1):

The beginning of my answer depends on the type of operation you want to pull the data from but I’m going to assume it’s a response from the HTTP operation.

You need to use square brackets and single quotes for what you want.  You need to use syntax like this ...

```
body('HTTP')['data']['alertContext']['condition']['allOf']['dimensions'][0]['value']
```

... or you can use `Parse JSON` but if the structure of your JSON can differ then you’ll need to adjust your schema so it can cater for it.

This link helps ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#expressions

Comment: Yeah i pull the response from a HTTP Request, the respone has a standard schema which i've attached, it comes from monitor alerts.

Comment: Cool, I’ve shown you what to do anyway.

Comment: I was able to get it without using parse json activity, from the http response with triggerBody()?['body']?['data']?['alertContext']?['condition']?['allOf'][0]?['dimensions'][0]?[value] I was able to get the output!

Comment: Ok, so my syntax helped, correct? If so, please flag it as the answer.